# URL masking for nginx server

Tags: nginx

I have nginx server. I'm trying to redirect .biz domain to .com but URL should be .biz only.

I have tried lots of redirection rule but it is not working.

My .com domain is already live. I want to search .biz domain but page should be same as .com

Comment: You try to hide one domain behind another?

Comment: So You mean Your .com domain is on another separate webserver and You want to proxy it through the .biz domain because You cannot move the .biz domain to the same the server the .com domain is hosted from - and do not want to deprecate the .biz domain with redirecting the browser to the .com?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [nginx rewrite module?](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)
Something like this should do the trick

```
server {
    listen <ip.address>:<port>
    server_name <domain>.biz
    location / {
        rewrite ^https://<domain>.biz/(.*)$ https://<domain>.com/$1
    }
}
```